# How to check Boolean for null?

Tags: java, wrapper, ternary-operator, null-check

I want to add a null check to my ternary operator which checks on a `Boolean isValue`:

```
public String getValue() {
    return isValue ? "T" : "F";
}
```

My task is:

> What if the Boolean(object) return null? Add a boolean check and return "" (empty String in case if its null).

Note that `isValue` is a `Boolean`, not `boolean`.

Comment: is `isValue` a primitive boolean? If it is, then it will never be null. Also, ternary is `a ? b : c`

Comment: To expand on what @Compass said, primitive types cannot be null, only Objects such as `Boolean` or `String`, not `int` or `boolean`.  Primitive types have inherit default values, for example `int` defaults to `0`.

Comment: @Nexevis it is an Object (Boolean)

Comment: @learn n rock I recommend you edit your question with that information then, you specifically use the term `boolean` which implies the primitive type.

Comment: Thank You @Nexevis my mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A terniary operator has the following syntax:

```
result = expression ? trueValue : falseValue;
```

Where `trueValue` is returned when the expression evaluates to `true` and `falseValue` when it doesn't.

If you want to add a null check such that when a `Boolean` `isValue` is `null` then the method returns `""`, it isn't very readable with a terniary operator:

```
String getValue() {
    return isValue == null ? "" : (isValue ? "T" : "F");
}
```

A statement like that could be better expressed with `if` statements. The body of the method would become

```
final String result;
if (isValue == null) {
    result = "";
} else if (isValue) {
    result = "T";
} else {
    result = "F";
}
return result;
```

Comment: public String getValue(){
if (isValue!= null) { return  isValue ? "T" ? "F" ;  } else {return "" ; }
}

Answer (score 3):

You are using the incorrect syntax for the ternary operator as pointed out from the comments which should be `isValue ? "T" : "F"`.  I suggest using a solution that mixes the ternary operator with a standard `if` statement to check for a `null` value.

Here is what that solution looks like:

```
public String getValue() {
    if (isValue == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return isValue ? "T" : "F";
}
```

This will check for `null` before anything else and return an empty `String` if the value is `null`.  Otherwise it will check the value as normal and return the `String` value of `T` or `F` for `true` or `false` respectively.

Comment: Thanks , i added my comment for the above answer which matches yours  @Nexevis

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
return Optional.ofNullable(isValue).map(t -> t ? "T": "F").orElse("");
```

Comment: I love the cleanliness of this.